# std::hex does not work as I expect

Tags: c++

I'm not used to C++, so bear with me...

Two bytes are read from a device and gets in a buffer.
It is then to be printed.

The code below is supposed to return the string "0x204D"
However, it returns "0x M" which in hex is 30 78 **20 4d**

So the hex is not decoded to ascii.

```
void vito_unit::decodeAsRaw(unsigned char *buffer, int bufferLen)
{
    std::stringstream *decodedClearText;
    decodedClearText = new std::stringstream;

    *decodedClearText << "0x" << std::hex;

    for (int i=0; i<bufferLen; i++) {
            *decodedClearText << buffer[i];
    }
    setValue(decodedClearText->str());
}
```

How should it be done?

Comment: Off topic: any reason you are using new to construct `decodedClearText`?

Comment: @PiotrNycz No, I'm just trying to fix another guy's code in a language I obviously does not understand ;-)

Comment: @BoPersson: Please, do not answer in the comments section.

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with `std::hex`.

When you stream a `[signed/unsigned] char`, its ASCII representation is used, because that is usually what is expected of `char`s.

You can stream a *number* instead by converting it to `int`. Then the feature that renders *numbers* in hexadecimal notation (i.e. `std::hex`) will be triggered.

You should also fix that memory leak and unnecessary dynamic allocation:

```
void vito_unit::decodeAsRaw(unsigned char const* const buffer, int const bufferLen)
{
    std::stringstream decodedClearText;
    decodedClearText << "0x" << std::hex;

    for (int i = 0; i < bufferLen; i++) {
       decodedClearText << +buffer[i];
    }

    setValue(decodedClearText.str());
}
```

The unary "+" performs an integral promotion to `int`.

Comment: That printed 0x200x4d, But with the orifinal   decodedClearText << "0x" << std::hex; the other changes work. But as it's only run once, no loop or daemonizing, it does not really matter ;-)

Comment: Using unary `+` to convert to int strikes me as far too clever.  Just use a static cast, or assign to a local int.  You probably need a `setw(2)` too.  Otherwise instead of "0x01020304", you'll end up with '0x1234'.

Answer (score 4):

`buffer[i]` is of type `unsigned char` and is thus printed as a character instead of its hexadecimal representation. You can cast the value to an `unsigned int` to avoid that.

```
void vito_unit::decodeAsRaw(unsigned char *buffer, int bufferLen)
{
    std::stringstream *decodedClearText;
    decodedClearText = new std::stringstream;

    *decodedClearText << "0x" << std::hex;

    for (int i=0; i<bufferLen; i++) {
            *decodedClearText << (unsigned int) buffer[i];
    }
    setValue(decodedClearText->str());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The hint from Bo Persson was what I needed.

```
 for (int i=0; i<bufferLen; i++) {
        *decodedClearText << (int)buffer[i];
}
```

did the trick.

Comment: Please, get rid of that `new` while you are changing the code.

Comment: ... and as I commented below, you really ought to stream in `std::setw(2)` for every character, otherwise instead of `0x0102`, you will end up with `0x12`!